# how to handle adding null values with eachother

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to input three numbers into TextFormFields. The controllers are `numOneController` and `numTwoController` for putting the percent and a `totalAmountController` for putting the the amount. I then want to check if the percents are in total 100 so i can display they are indeed so. When totalAmountController is empty(null) then its no problem to display that its an invalid input but when the `numOneController` and `numTwoController` are empty i get the error `Invalid number (at character 1)`. I know its the fact that handler can't add an empty number with another. But how can i handle this so i can check if its null then i want to assign a number 0 to add that automaticly.

```
  sumHandler() {
    var totalPrecent = int.parse(numOneController.text) +
        int.parse(numTwoController.text) ;

    var totalAmount = totalAmountController;

    if (totalPrecent == 100 && totalAmount.text.isEmpty == false) {
      debugPrint(totalPrecent.toString());
      debugPrint(totalAmount.text.toString());
    } else {
      debugPrint("invalid input");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution for this on: [Another exception was thrown: FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853750/another-exception-was-thrown-formatexception-invalid-number-at-character-1)

I had to use `try catch block`:

```
try {
        firstNumber = int.parse(numOneController.text);
      } on FormatException {
        firstNumber = 0;
      }
```

This way i can handle the exception and on FormatException i can assign the number 0.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp variable and store it with 0 and later if the textfield has values assign values to it. Like the following

```dart
sumHandler() {
    int firstNumber = 0;
    int secondNumber = 0;
    if(numOneController.text != "")
    {
      firstNumber = int.parse(numOneController.text);
    }
    if(numTwoController.text != "")
    {
      secondNumber = int.parse(numTwoController.text);
    }
    var totalPresent = firstNumber + secondNumber ;

    var totalAmount = totalAmountController;

    if (totalPresent == 100 && totalAmount.text.isEmpty == false) {
      debugPrint(totalPresent.toString());
      debugPrint(totalAmount.text.toString());
    } else {
      debugPrint("invalid input");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunatly i still get the error but i found a solution thankfully i will post it on OP

Answer (score 0):

Using the `tryParse` method and a default value would help...

---

```dart
 sumHandler() {
    var totalPrecent = int.tryParse(numOneController.text) ?? 0 +
        int.tryParse(numTwoController.text) ?? 0;

    var totalAmount = totalAmountController;

    if (totalPrecent == 100 && totalAmount.text.isEmpty == false) {
      debugPrint(totalPrecent.toString());
      debugPrint(totalAmount.text.toString());
    } else {
      debugPrint("invalid input");
    }
  }
```